# Do I need to replace the water heater vent pipes if they have salt corrosion?

Tags: water-heater, exhaust-vent

I was in my attic improving the insulation and I found that my exhaust pipe for the water heater has salt/corrosion all around the seams.

[image]

Based on what I found, this is either caused by inadequate intake ventilation or the roof vent was done improperly.  I'm wondering do I also need to replace the vent pipes, too?

Comment: As long as the pipe is intact I would not worry about it, in coastal regions with high wind water gets into the pipe not much but enough to dribble down the inside, as long as not rusted out I would not worry but to prevent further dribbles I would put a wind directional cap on it this way when the wind blows it creates a better draft and the ones I have used the leading edge is lower than the pipe opening so no more water getting in the pipe.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll unscrew a section and take a look inside.